# how to submit windows phone app to windows store

Tags: cordova, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

i have devloped a windows phone 8.1 ap.i want to submit it to the windows store.but its asking.appx file to upload but i dont have this exe .i have .xap file.is there any way to upload this .xap file for windows store.Again i tried for the windows phone store but i am getting same error as

```
You may have missed some information or not they are installed properly. After updating the page, try again.
```

(https://dev.windowsphone.com/it-it/AppSubmission/Application)

i am not understanding whats wrong because i am entering all data still getting same error.please help if anyone knows this.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're in the Windows Phone store and not the Windows Store (xap is phone only) you can upload the xap in the same place as you would upload an appx.

Submit the app:

[image: Submit app page]

Upload and describe your packages, Add New:

[image: Upload and describe your package]

Answer (score 1):

This is how you create the appx file:
[image: Create App Packages...]